# Where does SFTP store partial files?

Tags: sftp

I was trying to copy a large file to a remote host using SFTP, but unfortunately the process crashed.

I'm assuming that the SFTP `put` command works by creating some temporary file on the remote host, appending data to it until the copy is complete, then renaming to the target filename. However, I wasn't able to locate the temporary file on the remote host. I want to make sure it gets deleted and doesn't continue to occupy space.

I'm similarly curious where the partial file is stored when using the `get` command.

Comment: It would depend on the implementation, e.g. WinSCP, see https://winscp.net/eng/docs/temp_folders

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSH server nor client do not create any temporary files anywhere.

All transfers go directly to the destination path.